# Managing Sonata Admin with ROLES instead of ACL

Tags: symfony, authorization, acl, sonata-admin

My understanding in `ACL` is very limited and my use of `SonataAdminBundle` is very simple including two roles `ADMIN` and `SUPER_ADMIN`.

I do not need [this](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) complicated `ACL` in my project (VIEW, EDIT, LIST, DELETE). I would like to determine the access to a certain admin or action just by the role.

Is it a good practice:

- In twig instead of using `admin.isGranted()` or `admin.hasAccess()` to use the default `is_granted('SUPER_ADMIN')`?
- In controler or admin class to use `security.authorization_checker` `isGranted()`?

How do I determine which `ROLE` has access to which page? For example, showing only certain admin pages for `SUPER_ADMIN` in sidebar and not allowing to be accessed by `ADMIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonata role approach defines roles per admin class, included a special role `*_ALL` that grants complete access to related admin zone, so you could then group these `*_ALL` under `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` roles in your `role_hierarchy` (`security.yml` file) e.g.:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: 
        - ROLE_USER
        - ROLE_FOO_BUNDLE_BAR_ADMIN_ALL
        - ROLE_FOO_BUNDLE_BAZ_ADMIN_ALL
        # ...
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: 
        - ROLE_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH
        - ROLE_SU_BUNDLE_SU_ADMIN_ALL
        # ...
```

Following this inheritance approach, your can to assign just `ROLE_ADMIN` for ones users and `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` for other. Even you could do some subgroups of roles to specific actions.

Comment: I have like 20 admin classes, so I should list them all in heararchy?